# combine 2 identical jquerys with different triggers

Tags: jquery, refactoring

Probably a very simple question. I have 2 identical jquerys, one triggers when one field updates, one triggers when another updates. Can I combine the two so it says if This changes, or That changes do Function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#premium").change(function(){
            var sum = 0;
            $("#premium").each(function(){
                sum += +$(this).val(); 
            });
            var ff_budget = $("#ff_budget").val();
            var premium_difference = ff_budget-sum;
            $("#total_premium").html("£ "+sum);
            $("#premium_difference").html("£ "+premium_difference);
        });

    $( "#ff_budget" ).change(function() {
            var sum = 0;
            $("#premium").each(function(){
                sum += +$(this).val(); 
            });
            var ff_budget = $("#ff_budget").val();
            var premium_difference = ff_budget-sum;
            $("#total_premium").html("£ "+sum);
            $("#premium_difference").html("£ "+premium_difference);
        });

});
```

Comment: try with `$("#ff_budget, #premium").change(function(){})`

Comment: use a class on your elements.  Also `$("#premium").each(function(){ sum += +$(this).val(); });`  this won't work as ids are meant to be unique so the selector will only get the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can use multiple selectors separated by a comma. This should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#premium, #ff_budget").change(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $("#premium").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val(); 
        });
        var ff_budget = $("#ff_budget").val();
        var premium_difference = ff_budget-sum;
        $("#total_premium").html("£ "+sum);
        $("#premium_difference").html("£ "+premium_difference);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course these can be merged. I see that the code is identical for both the event listeners.

You can use [jQuery's multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) to achieve the desired results:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#premium, #ff_budget").change(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        $("#premium").each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val(); 
        });
        var ff_budget = $("#ff_budget").val();
        var premium_difference = ff_budget-sum;
        $("#total_premium").html("£ "+sum);
        $("#premium_difference").html("£ "+premium_difference);
    });
});
```